# Error installing graphlab

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pip, sudo, graphlab

I tried installing graphlab using the pip command where we enter the email address and product key in the command. I tried upgrading it. I am using the sudo pip command and I am working on a Mac. I am getting this exception every time and it fails. I can install the dmg but that is easy. I want to know how to fix this exception. The exception is as follows:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/karthik/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/karthik/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Users/karthik/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 725, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Users/karthik/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 756, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Users/karthik/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Users/karthik/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 266, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-zVJZnq-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to install anything with `sudo` and `pip`. Try just running `pip install ...`

Answer (score 0):

if you are on ipython notebook, try :

```
!pip install
```